# Bot Framework Skype for Business channel error

Tags: botframework

While adding the channel getting the below error;

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: This is currently being addressed by the Bot Framework team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2966#issuecomment-309171572), the fix for this issue has been deployed. If you are still running into problems for this, please leave a comment in the linked issue on GitHub and we will track the matter there.